# SUMIF of absolute values

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with values like that:

```
A          | B
10,55 €    | x
10,05 €    | 
-0,55 €    | x
7,55 €     | 
-88,50 €   | x
```

I want the absolute sum of all rows with `x` in B

I can get the sum of x rows with `=SUMIF(B2:B100; "x"; A2:A100)`

And the absolute sum of all A column with `=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A2:A100))`

But I don't know how to mix those 2 formulas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(B2:B100="x",ABS(A2:A100)))
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use an ArrayFormula in Google docs :

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(B2:B100="x",ABS(A2:A100),0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I approved the @anonymous-rabbit one because I'm more familiar with SUMPRODUCT